# Android SDK manager failed to download platform-tools

Tags: android, macos, android-sdk-tools

I'm trying to download the Android SDK using Android Studio on mac OSX. 
But it always fails with the following error

> Ignoring unknown package filter 'platform-tools'Warning: The package
>   filter removed all packages. There is nothing to install.
>            Please consider trying to update again without a package filter. Ignoring unknown package filter 'platform-tools'

Comment: try dowloading this http://dl.google.com/android/android-sdk_r24.4.1-macosx.zip and show the path

Comment: "Android SDK is missing , out of date, or it is missing templates."

Answer (score 1):

Do as bearded beast mentioned in the comments above and download http://dl.google.com/android/android-sdk_r24.4.1-macosx.zip and unzip somewhere.

Then start Studio, go to Configure > Project Defaults > Project Structure and set the "Android SDK location" to the path of the unzipped Android SDK.

(I would have just added a comment with this info - but I don't have enough rep...)

Comment: That download never completes for me.